# SwiftUI: animating tab item addition/removal in tab bar

Tags: animation, swiftui, tabview

In my app I add/remove a subview to/from a `TabView` based on some condition. I'd like to animate tab item addition/removal in tab bar. My experiment (see code below) shows it's not working. I read on the net that `TabView` support for animation is quite limited and some people rolled their own implementation. But just in case, is it possible to implement it?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showBoth: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Button("Test") {
                withAnimation {
                    showBoth.toggle()
                }
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("1", systemImage: "1.circle")
                }

            if showBoth {
                Text("2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                    }
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: moving `transition()` call to the `Label` passed to `tabItem()` doesn't work either.

Comment: Apple wants the TabBar to stay unchanged: **Avoid hiding the tab bar when people navigate to different areas in your app. The tab bar is a global navigation control for your app, so make sure it’s always visible. ** https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/ – so I suppose they also don't want it to animate.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the information. My purpose, however, is not about hiding/showinng tab bar, but hiding/showing a tab item in the bar. It works (see above code). The issue is it can't be animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented Apple wants the TabBar to stay unchanged throughout the App.
But you can simply implement your own Tabbar with full control:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentTab = "One"
    @State var showBoth: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                // Tab 1.
                VStack {
                    Button("Toggle 2. Tab") {
                        withAnimation {
                            showBoth.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                } .tag("One")
                
                // Tab 2.
                VStack {
                    Text("Two")
                } .tag("Two")
            }
            
            // custom Tabbar buttons
            Divider()
            HStack {
                OwnTabBarButton("One", imageName: "1.circle")
                
                if showBoth {
                OwnTabBarButton("Two", imageName: "2.circle")
                    .transition(.scale)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func OwnTabBarButton(_ label: String, imageName: String) -> some View {
        Button {
            currentTab = label
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: imageName)
                Text(label)
            }
        }
        .padding([.horizontal,.top])
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have implemented quite a few custom views and my current goal is to get my app finished as soon as possible, I'm trying to use the views provided by Apple as much as possible. Your example is simple and helpful. That, plus the fact that the stock TabView is unlikely to supports the feature, I'll accept your answer. Will certainly consider to use it in future. Thanks!